# How to transfer some code from a .tex file to a .cls file, and put in inside in another defintion, including TeX primitives?

Tags: macros, package-writing

I had a .tex file which had the following magical code to translate the *adadi* page number to its *roman* equivalent.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\aresame}[2]{%
  \aresame@massage\aresame@tempa{#1}%
  \aresame@massage\aresame@tempb{#2}%
  \ifx\aresame@tempa\aresame@tempb
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\def\aresame@massage#1#2{%
  \begingroup\let\@xp\expandafter\let\@nx\noexpand
  \everyeof{}%
  \catcode`{=9 \catcode`}=9
  \catcode`<=1 \catcode`>=2
  \begingroup\edef\x{%
    \endgroup\@nx\scantokens{\def\@nx\1<#2>\@nx\empty}%
  }\x
  \uppercase\@xp{\@xp\endgroup\@xp\def\@xp#1\@xp{\1}}%
}
\makeatother
```

accompanying with the following code:

```
\def\myadadipage{\getpagerefnumber{lastpreamblepage}} %this reads the page number in *adadi*, since we used \pagenumbering{adadi} for the preamble part of the document.
\newcounter{searchforadadi}
\loop
\relax%
\ifnum\value{searchforadadi} < 1000
\addtocounter{searchforadadi}{1}%
\aresame{\myadadipage}{\adadi{searchforadadi}}{\xdef\myromanpage{\roman{searchforadadi}}}{}%
\repeat
```

now I can use `\myromanpage` anywhere in my document, without any problem.

But

My question arises as:

> "How can I move these code to a *supplementary* `.cls` file and put them exactly inside another command, I am curious to see how can I define a command, *like this one*, but just works, **internally/locally** inside another command?"

Since when I simply copy all these codes from the `.tex` file to the `.cls` file, where I need to use the command `\aresame` inside a definition of another command, say `\@setabstract`, used to typeset/pageset the English *abstract/summary* page of the work,

```
\def\@setabstract{%
\newcommand{\aresame}[2]{%
  \aresame@massage\aresame@tempa{#1}%
  \aresame@massage\aresame@tempb{#2}%
  \ifx\aresame@tempa\aresame@tempb
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\def\aresame@massage#1#2{%
  \begingroup\let\@xp\expandafter\let\@nx\noexpand
  \everyeof{}%
  \catcode`{=9 \catcode`}=9
  \catcode`<=1 \catcode`>=2
  \begingroup\edef\x{%
    \endgroup\@nx\scantokens{\def\@nx\1<#2>\@nx\empty}%
  }\x
  \uppercase\@xp{\@xp\endgroup\@xp\def\@xp#1\@xp{\1}}%
}
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\if@bachelor
\else
\begin{framed}
Number of Pages:
\xdef\myadadipage{\getpagerefnumber{lastpreamblepage}}
\newcounter{searchforadadi}
\loop
\relax%
\ifnum\value{searchforadadi} < 1000
\addtocounter{searchforadadi}{1}%
\aresame{\myadadipage}{\adadi{searchforadadi}}{\xdef myromanpage{\roman{searchforadadi}}}{}%
\repeat
\pageref{LastPage} + \myromanpage
\end{framed}}%end of set abstract
```

I will receive an error like:

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \@setabstract.
<to be read again> 
                   1
l.697   \aresame@massage\aresame@tempa{#1
                                         }%
?
```

Let me clear that, if I paste these codes outside the definition it is globally accessible and no errors found! But I wanted to know if I can have them local just for `\@setabstract` function.

Thanks in advance!

This question is sequel to another TeX.SX question, which could be [found here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329722/how-can-i-check-if-the-value-of-a-variable-is-the-same-as-what-another-variable).

Comment: You seem to have copied your code in the middle of some other definition.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I need it just in that _command_ `\@setabstract`. What shall I do?

Comment: you haven't shown what you did so hard to say what you diid wrong but just copy the definitions to the class file (without `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` and they should work the same way do not put them inside another definition

Comment: @OmidGhayour The question is unanswerable as it stands because it explains nothing at all.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I found some definitions having one or more definitions inside them. So isn't anyway to define internal/local definitions/commands?

Comment: @egreg I try to restated the problem!

Comment: @OmidGhayour moving code from a tex file to a cls file should not cause issues. When you nest "definitions", lots of things can happen. At a minimum, you need to double the # signs (for example #1 becomes ##1). As you are messing with catcodes there may be other issues, but we really need an MWE to help you.

Comment: @OmidGhayour there is no point, in general a macro definition does not imply any scope for nested macros they still have definitions when the outer macro ends, so unless the definition depends on the arguments of the outer macro why do it? Certainly if you have some code that generates an error then you should show _that code_ not other parts of different documents that are error free

Comment: if you are asking about placing the definitions inside another, please change the title of the question and the example. Moving the definitions inside another has the same issues whether you do it in the same file or move the code to a different file, and moving the code to another file without nesting has no issues at all.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I changed the title.

Comment: you still haven't made the question answerable (the class file and tex primitives are not relevant) what is relevant is the nested definition that generates the error that you have not shown.

Comment: As I said, you probably are using the wrong approach to solving the problem you have; state it instead of asking how the code can be made to fit. It's quite likely that there's a simpler solution, when we know what the problem is.

Comment: @egreg I will add your name as an contributor to my `.cls` package. _for the magical code!_ :)

Comment: There's no need here to go to the effort of putting the definition into a group: why not just copy the code and _use_ it where you want it?

Comment: @JosephWright since it gives me an error!

Comment: @OmidGhayour The error you describe in the question would result from placing the code _inside another macro_, as already mentioned. But that would need a group to localise it and would be a waste of time: I can't see how the obvious approach of copying as-is would give an error.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I added the `\@setabstract` command which gives me the error.

Comment: @JosephWright I know the error is made by my insufficient knowledge of how to insert a command inside another. What I want is a solution telling me, how to put a command in another. Not telling me I get this just because I shouldn't put a simple (not ready to be included) command inside another.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 'basics' of the need to handle `#` correctly when nesting commands are covered in [What is the meaning of double pound symbol (number sign, hash character) ##1 in an argument?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42463/what-is-the-meaning-of-double-pound-symbol-number-sign-hash-character-1-in). Here, `\@setabstract` takes no arguments, so TeX will not allow `#1` to appear inside it (there is no argument to refer to). A nested definition inside `\@setabstract` needs the `#` doubling, so `#1` becomes `##1`, *etc.* Thus one might be tempted to to

```
\def\@setabstract{%
\newcommand{\aresame}[2]{%
  \aresame@massage\aresame@tempa{##1}%
   ....
```

This will avoid the error but is still not a great idea. As a macro language, TeX has no grouping associated with definitions, only with explicit groups. As such, with the above you'll get an error if you try to use `\@setabstract` twice as on the second use `\newcommand` will detect that `\aresame` is already defined. There is *no need* for `\aresame` to be defined within `\@setabstract` (which is normally only required if there is some context-dependence to allow for). Instead, you should simply define `\aresame` globally and use it within `\@setabstract`

```
\def\@setabstract{%
  ... % Code using \aresame
}
\newcommand{\aresame}[2]{%
  \aresame@massage\aresame@tempa{#1}%
  \aresame@massage\aresame@tempb{#2}%
  \ifx\aresame@tempa\aresame@tempb
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
```

---

To make a local definition you need a group. That might then look something like

```
\def\@setabstract{%
  \begingroup
    \def\aresame##1##2{%
      \aresame@massage\aresame@tempa{##1}%
      \aresame@massage\aresame@tempb{##2}%
      \ifx\aresame@tempa\aresame@tempb
        \expandafter\@firstoftwo
      \else
        \expandafter\@secondoftwo
      \fi
    }%
  \def\aresame@massage##1##2{%
    \begingroup\let\@xp\expandafter\let\@nx\noexpand
    \everyeof{}%
    \catcode`{=9 \catcode`}=9
    \catcode`<=1 \catcode`>=2
    \begingroup\edef\x{%
      \endgroup\@nx\scantokens{\def\@nx\1<##2>\@nx\empty}%
    }\x
    \uppercase\@xp{\@xp\endgroup\@xp\def\@xp##1\@xp{\1}}%
  }%
  % Use of \aresame here
  \endgroup
}
```

but there is little point. Putting all of the definitions inside `\@setabstract` makes the code harder to read without any obvious benefit, whilst you now have to watch that everything is typeset, saved globally or 'smuggled' out of the group. I'd strongly recommend not doing this.

Note that there's little point in using `\newcommand` in a 'throw-away' definition in a group, so I've dropped it in favour of `\def`.

Comment: Now I called it a good answer! As I said in the question I found a way to just get my job done by _globally_ defining `\aresame` but, I was looking a way to define it _locally_. I needed to use `##1` and `##2`. Thanks!

Comment: @OmidGhayour As I've said, just doubling the `#` tokens won't make the definition local: you'll also need a group (and then watch that you get your result out of the group if you need to retain the tokens).

Comment: @OmidGhayour as the answer says, with the local definition \@setabstract is not going to work the section time you use it.

Comment: @StrongBad Using the notes given by @Joseph, I made the local definition working by adding a an extra `#`, _i.e._ using `##1` and `##2` instead of `#1` and `#2.

Comment: @JosephWright And tell me about making it local, Please!

Comment: @OmidGhayour It's _not_ a local definition! After using `\@setabstract`, do `\show\aresame` and you'll find the definition is global (as expected), _unless you have a group_.

Comment: @JosephWright And tell me about making it local, Please! _How can I have group?_